# What oAuth handler code is needed when calling intuit.ipp.anywhere.setup()?

Tags: oauth, quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform

I am trying to create a "Connect to QuickBooks" button using IPP as described [here](https://ipp.developer.intuit.com/0010_Intuit_Partner_Platform/0025_Intuit_Anywhere/0020_Connect/0010_From_Within_Your_App/Call_the_Setup%28%29_Function).

The Javascript code provided by IPP, intuit.ipp.anywhere.setup() requires a parameter *grantUrl*, which points to an oAuth handler in my application. I don't have an oAuth handler yet, nor have I ever written one.

Is there any open source oAuth handler I can use here? If I need to write one, what should it look like?

Comment: What programming language?

Comment: Java servlet would be ideal. But I am open to whatever is available.

Answer (score 3):

Intuit has a Java DevKit that you can grab over here:

- http://docs.developer.intuit.com/0025_Intuit_Anywhere/0055_DevKits/0200_IPP_Java_DevKit

It has OAuth components which should do what you're asking:

- http://docs.developer.intuit.com/0025_Intuit_Anywhere/0055_DevKits/0200_IPP_Java_DevKit/0400_Basic_Usage_Pattern

Comment: Thanks. Those pages refer to IPP Java Dev Kit 2.0 and 3.0. I was only able to find 2.0. Where can I find 3.0?

Comment: 3.0 is in beta right now, and isn't available to the general public  yet.